# PyTest: How to skip all tests under the current directory if a certain condition is satisfied?

Tags: python, pytest

Is there a way to tell pytest (preferrably in `conftest.py`) that all test under that directory should be skipped if a certain condition is satisfied? For example, if some optional depedency is missing, then a test directory should be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the [`pytest_ignore_collect`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_ignore_collect) hook. For example let's say you have the directory below.

```
stackoverflow/
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── models.py
├── pytest.ini
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── conftest.py
    └── foo
        ├── __init__.py
        └── test_models.py
```

`test_models` has two tests in it. When I run it as-is from the root of the repository I get the following.

```
============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/stackoverflow, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 2 items                                                                                             

tests/foo/test_models.py ..                                                                             [100%]

============================================== 2 passed in 0.02s ==============================================
```

When we place the following in our `conftest.py` then no tests end up running.

```
from pathlib import Path

TO_IGNORE = "tests/foo"

def pytest_ignore_collect(path, config):
    # suppose our condition is some command line argument is passed in
    val = config.getvalue("-k")
    if val == "":
        here = Path.cwd().absolute()
        skip_fd = here / TO_IGNORE
        if skip_fd == path:
            return True

============================================= test session starts =============================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.9.1, pytest-6.2.2, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: ***/stackoverflow, configfile: pytest.ini
collected 0 items                                                                                             

============================================ no tests ran in 0.01s ============================================
```

You can make it as granular as you want with the file path depending on the structure of your repository. Just remember, `Path.cwd()` is wherever you are running `pytest` from.